# Matlab Image Processing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, lines

I'm facing a problem when displaying an image and using `hold on` to then plot `hough` lines on top of it. I want to store this image in a variable including lines on it and use it further. How can I do that?

Comment: This question has been re-posted by OP with different wording at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311160/how-save-image-from-figure-matlab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [copyobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/copyobj.html) for this. Or the [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html) function if you're making a movie.

Comment: im sorry i cant get this function copyobj into use. i give it the arguments (h,I) where h is the variable used to plot lines. e.g h = plotlines and I has the image that im showing in figure. im sorry to say but can u give detail about this solution?